# webcam cannot be accessed by WSL

Tags: webcam, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm very new to WSL. I want to run a python code on ubuntu shell on my win10 PC. This code needs access to webcam, but it seems that the webcam is not opened properly..I have checked online and I found several posts 1-2 years ago which said that the integrated webcam cannot be accessed by WSL..Is there any update or trick that can use webcam on WSL?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't still access the webcam in WSL but there are several ways to access the video stream in WSL. The most obvious one is converting your webcam to a web-based streaming protocol like RTSP, MPEG, FFMPEG streams ([example](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2019/12/opencv-web-camera-and-video-streams-in.html)) where you get almost similar experiences.

Also, there are many [applications](https://github.com/gen2brain/cam2ip) where you can make your webcam as an IPcam stream then use the stream URL instead of using the camera index in OpenCV or any other application.